# I am getting cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') in template using ngrx MockStore

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have encountered this error - *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')* which was resolved but this is referring me to the template and I don't know what I did wrong for getting this type of error.

```
debug.js:21 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at templateFn (template.html:12:23)
    at executeTemplate (_karma_webpack_/webp…20/core.mjs:12084:9)
    at refreshView (_karma_webpack_/webp…0/core.mjs:11969:13)
    at refreshComponent (_karma_webpack_/webp…0/core.mjs:13043:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (_karma_webpack_/webp…20/core.mjs:11759:9)
    at refreshView (_karma_webpack_/webp…0/core.mjs:12019:13)
    at detectChangesInternal (_karma_webpack_/webp…20/core.mjs:13187:9)
    at RootViewRef.detectChanges (_karma_webpack_/webp…20/core.mjs:13699:9)
    at ComponentFixture._tick (_karma_webpack_/webp…/testing.mjs:140:32)
    at _karma_webpack_/webp…/testing.mjs:153:22
```

In my constructor, I have an observable

```
constructor(
    private store: Store<{ customer: Customer, index: Index}>,
    ) {
    this.customer$ = this.store.select(customerSelector);
    this.index$ = this.store.select(indexSelector);
    console.log(this.customer$)
  }
```

In my unit test, I did use MockStore.

```
it('should retrieve the answer', () => {
       store.overrideSelector(customerSelector, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Joe'Bradford,
        gender: 'male'
    });
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    store.select(customerSelector).subscribe((mockTeam) => {
      expect(mockTeam).toEqual({
        id: 1,
        name: 'Joe'Bradford,
        gender: 'male'
      });
     })

    })
```

NOTE: the application works as it should except in the unit test that I am getting such error.

Template, I used async pipe and that is the line it was pointing to the error message.

```
 *ngIf="customer$ | async as customer"
```

I noticed that when I checked the console. The store is empty.

[image]

Comment: what's the value you are getting in `mockTeam`? Looks like you are getting `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, undefined and I know what is wrong. I used initialState and set it in  provideMockStore(), and I did this too   store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're testing here, but the snippet seems if you want to test the selector. For this, you don't need to render the component, nor create a mockstore.
You can just invoke the selector and verify the output.

This makes everything simpler, and also faster.

https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/testing-an-ngrx-project#selectors